# Choosing a MagicNumber or Signature for a Binary File Format

Tags: binary, file-formats

I'm defining some binary formats to encode some information and dump it to a file.

I want to place a MagicNumber/Signature at the beginning of files encoded in my format to be able to tell them apart from other types of files. My question is:

**How do I choose a good signature?**

I've been thinking about picking 4 bytes that I believe aren't used already, but this solution has issues:

1. I wouldn't know how to let the world know that the Magic Number I chose is used by my format. For instance I doubt my file format will be supported by [magic](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/magic.4.html) any time soon.
2. Someone else could choose the same Magic Number for a different file format without knowing that we're overlapping each other.
3. It seems bad to let people arbitrarily pick 4 bytes. It's going to lead to the same problems we have with IPv4 addresses. More problems actually, since no authority is assigning those 4 bytes and making sure they're not duplicated.

Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Create a 16 byte guid, and use that. Obviously make very, very sure that you don't lose the guid. There is no serious chance that someone else creates files unintentionally starting with this guid.

Now if you find a file, and it contains this guid in the right place, it's either a file in your file format, or a file in your file format apart from changes due to bugs or corruption, or a file intentionally created to mislead your application and attack the user's computer. So reading these files, your code must survive whatever is in the file, without allowing an attack. If the file deviates enough from the file format it should contain, then you should handle this as an error, and ignore what's in the file.

Comment: I would only add that, if you're going to make your own binary file format anyway, putting a 32 bit checksum at the very end of the file can be extremely handy.

Comment: Totally right. A checksum makes the case “corrupted file” very unlikely to go unrecognised. You still need to handle malicious files obviously.